# How to remove specific initial characters from a column in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have column by the name of phone_number and it consists different types of numbers for example:

| phone_number |
| --- |
| 078912354 |
| 93784385483 |
| 009378248448 |
| 776868886 |

So I want to remove all the initial numbers which starts with(0,93,0093). The expected result which I want is:

| phone_number |
| --- |
| 78912354 |
| 784385483 |
| 78248448 |
| 776868886 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test order by phone_number;

PHONE_NUMBER NEW_PHONE_NUMBER
------------ --------------------
009378248448
078912354
776868886
93784385483
```

Remove leading characters you mentioned:

```
SQL> update test set
  2    new_phone_number = regexp_replace(phone_number, '^(0093|093|93|0)');

4 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test order by phone_number;

PHONE_NUMBER NEW_PHONE_NUMBER
------------ --------------------
009378248448 78248448
078912354    78912354
776868886    776868886
93784385483  784385483

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot your answer solved my problem.